# Help me find the coordinates of a point $9$ on a circle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, polar-coordinates

This seems easy. But it isn't. The diameter is given as $16$ and it asks you to find the coordinates of point $9$. It's tempting to say that it is $(4, 4\sqrt{3})$, but that isn't the answer. What the heck am I doing wrong? *We can also assume that the area of each segment is equal*

[image: In this triangle, the diameter is 16. Find the coordinates of point (9)]

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got that? That is also not an option for an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Where is the origin of the coordinates?

Comment: The question doesn't give you the origin of the coordinates, which is why it becomes all the more difficult

Comment: Can you please write down all text of the question? From what you've shown, I would say that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$

and $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

Comment: Yeah, and that would yield the answer choice that I mentioned, which is not correct. At least it isn't an answer option.

Answer (score 1):

In parametric form, you have
$$x=a+r \cos(t) \qquad \text{and} \qquad y=b+r\sin(t)$$  So $$x_9=a+4 \qquad \text{and} \qquad y_9=b+4\sqrt 3$$